# Minimum, Maximum, and extreme points

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

1. where A,B, and C are constants 
   $$f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$$

(c) What are the sign restrictions on A, B and C for f(x) to attain a minimum value?

(d) What are the sign restrictions on A, B and C for f(x) to attain a maximum value?

Comment: Do you know how to determine whether a parabola of this sort is concave up or concave down?

Comment: 2nd derivative test? @JohnWaylandBales

Comment: That will work.

Comment: but I don't know how to do it with these letter, i can do it with numbers. These letters are throwing me off @JohnWaylandBales

Comment: The letters are constants, treat them as if they were numbers. For example, $\dfrac{d}{dx}ax^3=3ax^2$.

Comment: I understand that, I apologize,  i meant to ask what do they mean by sign restrictions? @JohnWaylandBales

Comment: If $A$ is $5$ is $f$ concave up or down?  Did it matter what $B$ or $C$ are?  If $A$ is $3$ is $f$ concave up or down?  If $A$ is $-2$ is $f$ concave up or down?  If $A$ is zero, is it concave up or down?  Generalize this... "If $A$ is (*insert description here*) then (*insert conclusion here*)"

Comment: They mean should they be restricted to being positive or negative.

Comment: I don't really understand, @JMoravitz

Comment: Can you answer *any* of my questions at all?  Start with just the first question... If $A$ is $5$, is $f$ concave up or concave down?

Comment: If A is positive can it have a maximum?  Can it have a minimum?  Does it have to have a maximum or minimum?  Same questions if A is negative?  Same questions for whether B or C are positive negative or zero.  Just answer those questions.  That's all they are asking.

Comment: Thanks, and that's a lot of writing. @fleablood

Answer (score 0):

Answer these 20 questions, true or false and give a reason.  That is *all* the question is asking.

1) If $A$ is positive $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ will always have a maximum.  True or False.

2) If $A$ is positive $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ will always have a minimum.  True or False.

3) If $A$ is negative $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ may or may not have a maximum.  True or False.

4) If $A$ is negative $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ may or may not have a minimum.  True or False.

5) If $B$ is positive $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ will always have a maximum.  True or False.

6) If $B$ is positive $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ will always have a minimum.  True or False.

7) If $B$ is negative $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ may or may not have a maximum.  True or False.

8) If $B$ is negative $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ may or may not have a minimum.  True or False.

9) If $C$ is positive $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ will always have a maximum.  True or False.

10) If $C$ is positive $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ will always have a minimum.  True or False.

11) If $C$ is negative $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ may or may not have a maximum.  True or False.

12) If $C$ is negative $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ may or may not have a minimum.  True or False.

13) If $B$ is zero $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ will always have a maximum.  True or False.

14) If $B$ is zero $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ will always have a minimum.  True or False.

15) If $B$ is zero $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ may or may not have a maximum.  True or False.

16) If $B$ is ero $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ may or may not have a minimum.  True or False.

17) If $C$ is zero $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ will always have a maximum.  True or False.

18) If $C$ is zero $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ will always have a minimum.  True or False.

19) If $C$ is zero $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ may or may not have a maximum.  True or False.

20) If $C$ is zero $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ may or may not have a minimum.  True or False.

Comment: Eh... not literally though., for example one of the conclusions should involve the signs of $A$ and $B$ simultaneously, and the overall answer can be written in a single short phrase

Comment: Well, yes.  But the 20 answers can be combined to a single sentence.  I'm just trying to hammer the point home.

Comment: how can it be combined to a single sentence? @fleablood

Comment: "The quadratic expression will have a maximum when.... and will have a minimum when....."  You have to do *some* work you know.